# Split a string in Python having parenthesis (multiple splitters)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string, for example:

> "ab(abcds)kadf(sd)k(afsd)(lbne)"

I want to split it to a list such that the list is stored like this:

> a 
>   b
>   abcds
>   k
>   a
>   d
>   f
>   sd
>   k
>   afsd
>   lbne

I need to get the elements outside the parenthesis in separate rows and the ones inside it in separate ones.
I am not able to think of any solution to this problem.

Comment: I have tried using the split function. but it separates only using one character. I have also tried using a flag to mark whether I'm in the parenthesis or not and then append depending on flag.

Comment: By appending I mean that if I'm in the parenthesis then I'll append the string in that index of the list. Else I'll add a new element to the main list. @kartik

Comment: Your flag idea sounds like it would work. Post the code and we'll debug it.

Comment: What should happen if you have nested parentheses (e.g. ```"ab(cf(jsw))"```)?

Comment: There aren't any nested parenthesis in the input.

Comment: @kevin I have made the same code as posted by Nick Bailey in the answer. I was wondering if there is some shorter method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. The really easy one is to just iterate over the string. For example:

```
in_parens=False
buffer=''
for char in my_string:
    
    if char =='(':
       in_parens=True
    elif char==')':
       in_parens = False
       my_list.append(buffer)
       buffer=''
    elif in_parens:
       buffer+=char
    else:
       my_list.append(char)
```

The other option is regex.

I would suggest regex. It is worth practicing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use iter to make an iterator and use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to extract the strings between the parens:

```
it = iter(s)
from itertools import takewhile
print([ch if ch != "(" else  "".join(takewhile(lambda x: x!= ")",it)) for ch in it])
['a', 'b', 'abcds', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'sd', 'k', 'afsd', 'lbne']
```

If `ch` is not equal to `(` we just take the char else if ch is a `(` we use takewhile which will keep taking chars until we hit a `)` .

Or using `re.findall` get all strings starting and ending in `()` with `\`((.+?))` and all other characters with :

```
print([''.join(tup) for tup in re.findall(r'\((.+?)\)|(\w)', s)])
['a', 'b', 'abcds', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'sd', 'k', 'afsd', 'lbne']
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the magic of 're.split' and some logic.

```
import re
string = "ab(abcds)kadf(sd)k(afsd)(lbne)"
temp = []
x = re.split(r'[(]',string)
#x = ['ab', 'abcds)kadf', 'sd)k', 'afsd)', 'lbne)']
for i in x:
    if ')' not in i:
        temp.extend(list(i))
    else:
        t = re.split(r'[)]',i)
        temp.append(t[0])
        temp.extend(list(t[1]))
print temp
#temp = ['a', 'b', 'abcds', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'sd', 'k', 'afsd', 'lbne']
```

Have a look at difference in append and extend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try: [Python re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). If you are new to re it may take a bit of time but you can do all kind of string manipulations once you get it.

```
import re
search_string = 'ab(abcds)kadf(sd)k(afsd)(lbne)'

re_pattern = re.compile('(\w)|\((\w*)\)') # Match single character or characters in parenthesis

print [x if x else y for x,y in re_pattern.findall(search_string)]
```

Comment: Can you give an example for a regex that would do this?

Comment: Why so many down votes, I just wanted to point the OP in the right direction. Anyways I will add in the answer.

Comment: But this will not do what the author asks for, e.g. `"a(bc)"` would produce `["a", "bc", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: No, it won't. It will produce ['a', '(bc)']. But it does the have the extra parenthesis which the OP does't want.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Parenthesis could be avoided with `[i for g in re.findall('(\w)|\((\w*)\)', search_string) for i in g if i]` or dozens of other solutions.

Comment: Yup, Thanks for the suggestion :) I have the answer.